# CakePHP Form Submission with Results in Url

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

How do I submit a form using the form helper and have the reply of that submission have a url with what was searched for?

I submit this code:

```
 <?php echo $form->create('Search', array('action' => 'results', 'type' => 'post')); ?>
    <?php

            $options = array
            (
                'size' => 45,
                'id' => 'search',
                'tabindex' => 1,
                'maxlength' => 250
            );

            echo $form->text('Search.query', $options);
        ?>
```

So when I submit the form with the words "Hello World", I want the resulting url to be:

```
 [domain]/searches/results/Hello+World
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do a redirect to get this exact URL. Submitting a form using GET would result in `/searches/results?SearchQuery=Hello+World`. For my taste that would be perfectly adequate, but if you want a pretty URL, do this in your controller:

```
class SearchesController extends AppController {
    public function results($query = null) {
        if (!$query && $this->data) {
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'searches', $this->data['Search']['query']));
        }

        // search
     }
}
```

Note that this requires one extra roundtrip to the server.

Comment: i'm having trouble when i search for words that have a space...seems weird

Comment: What trouble in particular? Examples?

Comment: nevermind, having some caching issues and debug code messing things up

Comment: also added another if clause that stated if $query and $this->data exists, then they also need to be equal, or else redirect